# How to use typedef of function signature as type parameter to std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, signature

There must be a difference between a typedef of a function and the use of a bare function type when used as a template type parameter.

I.e., consider

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(int)> TF1;

typedef void(*FooFn)(int);
typedef std::function<FooFn>     TF2;

int main() {
    TF1 tf1;
    TF2 tf2;
    return 0;
}
```

I can create a `TF1` but not a `TF2` (error: `aggregate 'TF2 tf2' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`).  (See [ideone example](https://ideone.com/h6LIFv).)

Is there a way to use a typedef of a function (signature) as a template type parameter; specifically, as the type parameter to `std::function`?

(No C++11 tag because I'm interested in `boost::function` as well on non-modern compilers.  But a C++11 answer would also be appreciated, if the language changed in some way to enable this.)

Comment: The type `std::function` does not take function pointers as template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::function` object can store any *Callable* object including a function pointer (you could initialize `tf1` with a pointer of type `FooFn`).

But the template parameters are of type `R` result type and `Args` arguments.

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

EDIT:
The following example changes the `FooFn` typedef from function pointer to function type.

https://ideone.com/XF9I7N

Comment: In your example you got it to work with `typedef void(FooFn)(int);std::function<FooFn>     TF2;` Is that worth mentioning, or is that roughly what you're saying but I just don't understand?

Comment: @Tas It is pretty much the same thing, I changed the `typedef` to be an `R(Args...)` type instead of a function pointer.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could typedef the signature _without_ the `*` (for pointer)!  (The ideone example was what I used - I think this answer could be improved by linking to it in case the comments above at the question disappear.)

Answer (score 4):

`std::function` needs a function type, while `FooFn` is a pointer (to function) type, not a function type.  Use the metaprogramming helper template `remove_pointer` to convert it:

```
typedef std::function<std::remove_pointer<FooFn>::type> TF2;
```

Comment: I was so desperate for this answer that I could kiss you on the mouth right now :)